# Checking if a store is open. MySQL node.js Business Logic

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, logic

given a users time, I am trying to figure out whether a store is open or closed.

My HoursOfOperation DB looks like this:

```
dayid | openTime | closeTime
  3       1500      2400
  4       1500      2400
  5       1500       100
  6       1500       200
```

dayid is sunday - saturday: 0-6 respectively.

openTime and closeTime range between 0-2400.

If the user time is say 1800 on a wednesday, that's easy. The place is open. But what if it's 1AM on a saturday? The greater than openTime returns false, and the less than closeTime check is true. false && true equals false.

I've tried multiple types of data and business logic. But I'm struggling to wrap my head around this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logic like this:

```
where dayid = @dayid and
      ( (openTime < closeTime and @timetocheck between openTime and closeTime) or
        (openTime > closeTime and @timetocheck not between closeTime and openTime)
      )
```

The logic reads as:

- If `openTime` is less then `closeTime`, then the store is open when the requested time is between them.
- If `openTime` is greater than `closeTime`, then typically `closeTime` would be in the wee hours of the morning.  The store is closed between the `closeTime` and `openTime`.  Hence, the store is open at other times.

Comment: Cool, code kept in sql is great. But, can you give an explanation on how it covers the use cases please? It does make sense. But I'd just like your mind's understanding of it.

Comment: Again, it definitely works. But do you mind explaining between the parentheses the logic? Really neat LinkedIN btw